# Batch file Get Status of Windows Update GUI Window

Tags: batch, windows-update, gui, status

I have a batch file which calls the windows update routine (call explorer ms-settings:windowsupdate) and then use a sendkeys script to send keypresses until the "Check for Updates" button is in focus and to then toggle it. I would like to determine if the "Windows Update" Window is still open before moving on to the next part of the batch file without having to use the (taskkill /f /im "SystemSettings.exe") command to close it (e.g. for when I decide to manually close the interface window). I haven't figured out what query to use to find out what the status of that window is; that is, whether it's still open or has been closed. Querying with (sc query "wuauserv") simply indicates if the service is running [which for me always is] rather than if the "Windows Update" window is open.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . I think it would be best if you could edit your question and add the full batch script, as well as your intent with this script. While I'm not sure there is a way to "get status of Windows window", perhaps there is a better way to do the thing you want altogether (checking for updates and doing something with it can be done in command line directly.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions, Yisroel. It turns out that SystemSettings.exe is what's running when the Windows Update Window is open. That stops when the window closes so I can use this to determine if the window is open or not:

```
:Loop
cls
echo.
echo    Close the update window 
echo    when update conmpletes . . .
echo.
set SS=""
for /f "tokens=1" %%S in ('tasklist /m SystemSettings* ^| findstr /i /C:"SystemSettings.exe"') do set SS=%%S
echo    String found=[%SS%]
if "%SS%"=="SystemSettings.exe" timeout /T 3 /nobreak>nul & goto Loop
echo    Success - no longer found SystemSettings in tasklist
```

Comment: Oh, that's simple and people would immediately know to answer that, the issue is that your question didn't say it want's to know if the Settings window is open, it said it needs to know if the Windows Update window (which is just one potential page that might be open when SystemSettings.exe is.)

Comment: You're right, Yisroel.  I wasn't certain that the Windows Update window was covered by the SystemSettings group; it was that one window that I was interested in. Now that I know that when SystemSettings closes, the WindowsUpdate window is closed as well, I know I can query systemsettings.exe rather than something more specific to determine if the window is still open or not.
I hadn't allowed enough time between when it closed, and when I checked to see if it was still running. The Loop took care of that by repeatedly checking until systemsettings.exe had quit after the window itself closed.

Comment: Part of the uncertainty regarding the Windows Update window was that I opened it using a specific command (call explorer ms-settings:windowsupdate) so thought I needed to be specific in querying that exact window rather than simply systemsettings.exe.